# What is the equivalent of `git clean -f -d -x` in magit

Tags: emacs, magit

I expect to be able to
`z -a z` in  `magit-status` and be able to `stash pop / z p` without problems. However stashing everything in magit apparently does  imply saving ignored directories to the stash, but *not* delete it from the working directory.

The result is that you can't simply pop the stash, since the stash will try to pop files in ignored directories, which are already present.

Replay:

```
git init 
mkdir ignoreme
touch ignoreme/ignoremefile
git init
echo ignoreme > .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "add ignore file"
emacs
  m-x magit-status; z; -a;z
git stash pop
  ignoreme/ignoremefile already exists, no checkout
  Could not restore untracked files from stash
```

Answer (score 5):

You can run <kbd>C-u M-x magit-clean</kbd> or <kbd>!! clean -xd</kbd>.

(Your suggested command is missing `-x` flag.  `git clean -d` will
remove untracked, but not ignored, directories.  )

Comment: You are right about the `-x`. I updated the Q. It's a pity that magit does not cater to the use-case completely and you still have to use two commands to stash completely.